# I'd like to know any resource to check the Measure Word for a given word

Tags: measure-word

There are many resources that offer a list of Measure Words, but I'm interested in finding a resource where I can type a word and get its Measure Word back.

Thank you very much in advance to anyone who knows about it.

Comment: 小马词典 contains CL for most nouns, e.g.姐姐 jiě jie older sister; CL:个;弟弟 dì di younger brother; CL:个,位;警察 jǐng chá police; policeman; policewoman; CL:个;鱼 yú
fish; CL:条,尾;狮子 shī zi lion; CL:只,头;计算机 jì suàn jī computer; calculator; CL:台

Comment: https://www.mdbg.net/ (which is based on the open CEDICT project and has about 120 thousand entries) also displays the classifier, search for a noun and look for  'CL:', e.g. ```马 mǎ​ horse / CL: 匹 / horse or cavalry p...```

Answer (score 1):

"measure word" is called "classifier" in days gone by. the most completed list that i know, is in "**中西譯語妙法**" (page 4 - 26); 43 classifiers, with 370+ examples. this book was printed in shanghai, in 1893. you may download it from internet archive (which was blocked in xxxxx nowadays; well,  guess where?)

[first lessons in chinese](https://archive.org/details/lessonschinese00yaterich)

[image: page 4 of first lessons in chinese]

though this book talked about english and shanghai dialect, i think that most of these classifiers are valid and appropriate, in modern usage.

have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are other resources on the Web/etc., but the Pleco app on iOS (and other platforms I think) has a nice built-in dictionary that displays the measure word in the listing for each Chinese noun.